# What is the best way to work with C++ model and TableView?

Tags: qml, qt5, mvp, qtableview

I rather newcomer in QML and can't find the best solution to work with QML `TableView` regarding C++ models. Almost all google's links say that I should use `QAbstractTableModel`. However, the problem in using this model (or better to say Presenter) is that I shoud emit `dataUpdated` every time anything is changed in real data.

But my approach is to create `RowPresenter` with `QObject`-derived properties for every column-cell (e.g. `NameCellPresenter`, `StatisticsCellPresenter` etc.) All these cell objects have complex data and it should be displayed in cell via properties. Moreover, I could display several types of data in one cell. And nobody, except these cell presenter objects, will never know about changing (`RowPresenter` or List of `RowPresenter` will only do their function of creating/removing...)

The questions are:

- How could I efficiently update to QML the number of rows and rows from `QList<RowPresenter>` (without resetting `ContextProperty`) ?
- Are there any methods to work with `QAbstractTableModel` in such way: only cell presenter knows about changing, and displaying complex data in one cell that could be changed independent from different threads?

Comment: A `TableView` actually works with a list model, not a table model. Simply wrap up your list of rows in a `QAbstractListModel`, which you then expose to QML in the usual way. You will then use the `roleNames` method to map the fields within each row to the `TableView` columns.

Comment: TableView could work with any kind of QAbstractItemModel and QAbstractTableModel inherits it. About using QAbstractList, I need to create role for every item I want to display, moreover I need to emit data Updated form List model, and particular this issue I want to avoid.

Comment: I would like to use smth like QObjectList-based model in [Using C++ Models with Qt Quick Views](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html), but with the ability to know when list changed